# drag element to specific div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

want to drag element to specific div and if not dragged to this div will comeback (revert)
using jQuery UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div id="draggable" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border: solid 1px #000;">Drag me!</div>
<div id="droppable" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; border: solid 1px #000;">Drop here!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ revert: true });
 $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  accept: "#draggable",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
   // the draggable is dropped
  }
 });
</script>
```